# iScroll url hash change support

Tags: javascript, iscroll

This is a known issue for iScroll and it only seems to happen in iOS5 where the menu completely stops working. All my sub links in iScroll are hash anchors. Does anyone have a workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I handled it was to hijack the anchor links themselves and replace them with `scrollToElement` calls instead.

```
// Hijack hash anchors and scroll to them
$('a').click ( function (e) {
    var id = $(this).attr('href');
    if (id.substr(0,1) == '#') {
        e.preventDefault();
        setTimeout( function() {
            scroller.scrollToElement ( id, 0 );
        }, 0);
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
});
```

This code should only hijack links that begin with `#`. It then handles the `scrollToElement` in a `setTimeout` which fixes some other intermittent bugs. It works well on my end as long as your anchors are properly named with id's. If you are using `name` attributes instead of `id` attributes, you'll need to rewrite these.

This code will copy `name` attributes and put them in the `id` attribute if it is blank. You probably won't need this, though.

```
$('a').each (function (i, e) {
    var n = $(e).attr('name');
    var id = $(e).attr('id');
    if ( typeof id == 'undefined' || id === null || id === '') {
        $(e).attr('id', n);
    }
});
```